# Names of main Tintin characters in Latin?

Tags: contemporary-latin, names

The website [Tintinologist.org](http://www.tintinologist.org/guides/characters/names.html) gives the following suggestions but it is not complete for the Latin language.

What would be some good Latin names for the various Tintin characters ?

[image: Names of Main Tintin Characters in Different Languages]

Other characters include:

- Bianca Castafiore
- Rastapopoulos
- Nestor
- Jolyon
- Wagg
- Dr. Müller
- General Tapioca
- General Alcazar

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Adventures_of_Tintin_characters#Main_characters

Comment: Haddock, according to https://aquaticallatin.info/haddock is Melanogrammus aeglefinus (Linnaeus, 1758). But a much more attractive name was given to a left-eyed flatfish called the megrim. The latin for that is ***Lepidorhombus whiffiagonis*** 
https://britishseafishing.co.uk/megrim/ How about ***whiffiagonis*** for short?

Answer (score 7):

The Finnish medical doctor Ylermi Luttinen (assisted by Teivas Oksala and Maija-Leena Kallela and Erkki Palmén) has translated several Tintin books into Latin.
They cannot be properly published as the rights are prohibitively expensive, but he has kindly given me some copies.
The ones I have are
*De loto Carulea* (The Blue Lotus),
*7 globi crystallini* (The Seven Crystal Balls),
*Auris fracta* (The Broken Ear),
*Cancer forficibus aureis* (The Crab with the Golden Claws), and
*Templum solis* (Prisoners of the Sun).

I found no character list, but here are the ones that I could locate (French name in parentheses when different):

- Tintin is Titinus.
- Snowy (Milou) is Milulus.
- Captain Haddock is Nauarchus.
- Professor Calculus (Tournesol) is Helianthus.
- Thomson and Thompson (Dupond et Dupont) are Clodius and Claudius.
- Rastapopoulos is Rastapopulus.
- Nestor is Nestor.

There are several named minor characters, but these are the central ones.
Let me know if you would like a name of a character appearing in one of these stories, and I can try to find it.

Comment: Amazing stuff. This is of course no "official" translation but there is no such thing anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in the late 80's, two titles of Tintin were published in Latin:

- De Insula Nigra

[image]

- De Sigaris Pharaonis

[image]

The first one only contains the characters Tintin, Milu, and the two detectives. The vignettes available [here](https://www.arretetonchar.fr/de-titini-et-miluli-facinoribus-de-insula-nigra/) confirm the names in the above list, based on standard declensions (*Tintinus*, *Milulus*, *Clodius* and *Claudius*).

The second book also contains Rastapopoulos, but I haven't found a page online with his name. The image [here](https://www.bdnet.com/catalogue_detail_Tintin-Latin-De-Sigaris-Pharaonis--9782203321052) has, funnily enough, his first appearance in the comic but doesn't mention his name. However, being a Greek name suggests to me the Latin was probably equivalent. Greek experts in this forum may know better than me.

On another note, [this post](https://www.tintinologist.org/forums/index.php?action=vthread&forum=2&topic=3004&page=2#msg26273) from 2009 mentions a Finnish medical doctor called Ylermi Luttinen was translating Tintin's books into Latin. Goolging that name it seems he is part of the recurrent event called "[Athenis Finlandiae](http://www.athenisfinlandiae.com/english.htm)", which promotes Latin in Finland, meaning he might be proficient in Latin. I haven't been able to find a contact or website (and the one linked on the post doesn't work anymore). Maybe Joonas can help on this?

Comment: I edited the last paragraph a bit. I actually have Ylermi's translations, and I might write up something about them. // Can you include actual names in the answer? The links might rot.

Answer (score 3):

From *De Sigaris Pharaonis*, Hergé, Casterman, 1990, translation into latin by Caelestis Einchenseer:
[image]
[image]

From *De Insula Nigra*, Hergé, Casterman, 1987, translation into latin by Caelestis Einchenseer:
[image]

Tintin ― Titĭnus

Dupont et Dupond ― Clodius et Claudius

Rastapopoulos ― Rastapopūlos

Philémon Siclone ― Philēmon Cyclon